# Is it possible for a malicious website to steal my cookies from another website?

Tags: cookies, iframe, security

From what I understand `document.cookie` only gets your cookies for the current site you are on.  Would it be possible for a malicious site to get around this by using an iFrame, modifying my HTTP header, making a request to the target site or some other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DNS Rebinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) can be used to bypass Same Origin Policy (SOP) used by browsers to prevent one web site reading other website data like cookies, dom etc

[Here](http://vimeo.com/7907871) is a great video to learn how it works and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 9):

One way to do this would be through cross-site scripting attacks.  [This](https://jehiah.cz/a/xss-stealing-cookies-101) is a short overview of how cookie-stealing works with XSS.

Answer (score 2):

These techniques in general will not work. Iframes deny programmatic access to properties like page content and cookies for pages on a different domain. Likewise, Javascript HTTP requests are only allowed to the same domain as the requesting page.

Comment: Why do you say generally?  Can this happen if I'm using an old browser or something?

Comment: JavaScript and HTML are standards; web browsers implement them differently and some may not pay attention to safety. However, one would be hard-pressed to find a recent release of a modern web browser without such checks in place.